# Scrollrect in unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollrect

i just want to create a scrollrect that have a Repetitious Background image i set the image mod to tilled to have Repetitious image but image will go over the panel borders how i can have scrollrect with Repetitious image please help me

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can add two images, above and below main scrollrect content, so when you reach end of a content, tiled image still be visible. Here is an example  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E95i8.png)

Comment: Can i have your source code to have all details i can't understand exactly what you saying( if that is possible)

Comment: Hi, in this example was no source code at all, only work with Unity editor - so, we have , for example, vertical scrollrect content with background tiled image. Now we have a problem - if we move content to its highest or lowers point we will see blank background, because we will be no content where, so we can add two additional UI elements with image component - one above highest point (starts from Y 1,1 anchor and pivot of main content , and one below point Y 0, 0 of main content) Please look at the image, linked to my previous answer to you

Comment: tnx this help alots

Comment: just leaving comments

Comment: commentssssssss

Comment: why this so be hard

Comment: call me this    sadad